# htaccess redirects and Wordpress

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I am migrating from an ancient static web site to Wordpress.

In the old site, I used htaccess and RewriteRule to simplify URLs and mask the underlying parms. One case was:

```
RewriteRule ^definition/([^/]+) /display-definition?word=$1 [NC]
```

This allowed people to specify a URL of:

```
domain.com/definition/love
```

And under the sheets executed instead:

```
domain.com/display-definition?word=love
```

I have created and tested the new Wordpress page, and manually passing it the parameter works fine. The htaccess redirect does not, and instead tosses visitors to the default Wordpress 404 page.

I have tried placing the RewriteRule in various places in htaccess, but the results do not differ.

Current attempted htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^definition/([^/]+) /display-definition?word=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^murphyism/([^/]+) /display-murphy?id=$1 [NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do this in htaccess with wordpress. You should instead add a rewrite rule using **add_rewrite_rule** and then register the query var.

You would be looking at adding to rewrite rules to handle your two rewrites:

```
RewriteRule ^definition/([^/]+) /display-definition?word=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^murphyism/([^/]+) /display-murphy?id=$1 [NC]
```

**For Definition:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse251676_definition_rewrite_rule' );
function wpse251676_definition_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'definition/([a-z0-9A-Z_-]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=display-definition&definition_word=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

**For Murphyism:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse251676_murphyism_rewrite_rule' );
function wpse251676_murphyism_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'murphyism/([a-z0-9A-Z_-]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=display-murphy&murphy_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

**You can then register the query vars with:**

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse251676_query_vars' );
function wpse251676_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'definition_word';
    $query_vars[] = 'murphy_id';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

With this you can then use the builtin **`get_query_var`** in your template files or wherever necessary to get the variables instead of using **`$_GET['variable']`**

```
$word = get_query_var('definition_word'); //$_GET['definition_word']
$id   = get_query_var('murphy_id');       //$_GET['murphy_id']
```

**NOTE:** It's always good practice to prefix your variables so they have a unique name different from any formally defined or futureones

**References:**

- [**Rewrite API**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)
- [**add_rewrite_rule**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)
- [**Wordpress Query Vars**](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars)
- [**query_var filter**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars)
- [**get_query_var**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

Comment: Thanks. A couple of follow-ups if I may:

1) Where does this code get added? In other threads it looks as if it is added to theme files. Since I am using a commercial theme, which gets updated regularly, it seems bad practice to edit those files and thus be forced to re-edit them constantly.

2) This approach requires finding and revising every instance of $_GET, which is a painful new labor. to the project. It there simply no way of getting htaccess to do what is needed as opposed to this approach?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can add this to the functions file of a child theme, define your custom templates in the child theme and also add your query vars to it. That way, an update to the parent theme doesn't affect anything you've done

Comment: I finally found time to look into your approach (thanks again for the guidance). I have run into a problem with the query function (the redirects appear to be working).

Comment: What problem are you having with the query function?

Comment: I found the problem. The original add_filter code has a different function name in the 2nd parm than the function itself (wpse26388_ and wpse251676_).

Comment: Oh, my bad, please mark as the correct answer. Updated

Comment: Again, many thanks. Your approach is working very well.

One follow-up for which you might have a slick answer.

Many of the inbound links for the old site have apostrophes in the (i.e. domain.com/murphyism/Adam's_Law_of_Impossible). Wordpress doesn't handle this well, producing 404 errors.

Is it possible to to use add_rewrite_rule to change the apostrophe into %27, which my testing indicates would be processed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The standard WordPress .htaccess file will do this for you if you select one of the "pretty permalinks" in the Settings / Permalinks page, like the "posts" option.

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I can't seem to get that to format properly, so check the source page here -
https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

For more info, see the Codex page - https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#mod_rewrite:_.22Pretty_Permalinks.22

Comment: Thanks, but I am not seeing the connections here.

First, I am using the de facto htaccess generated by Wordpress, and attempting to add the line in question So far, we are aligned.

The original static site is at http://www.cynical.ws. As you can see there are other aspects aside from word definitions, so it is unclear how using the pretty permalinks function would correctly address the goals. I may be missing the obvious though.